# Scribus: PDF document seems different than in Ubuntu Document Viewer

Tags: pdf, scribus

I've opened a PDF file with Scribus but it seems quite different then it seems in the Ubuntu Document Viewer.

Should I export the file to some other format if I want to edit the files content directly from scribus?

I just want to change some text in the file but Scribus trats the PDF file more as an image than as a text file (not sure if it's the natural state).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scribus can read PDF files but is not a PDF editor.
It's not the right tool for tweaking little bits of text in a PDF.

Also, PDF is not a format that is meant to be further edited.
But, if I had to modify one, I would first try Inkscape.
Then LibreOffice Writer / Draw.
In the past I've used flpsed, but i'm not sure I would still use it.

That being said:

- If you're using a stable Scribus 1.4.x, all you can do is:

  - load the PDF as a background image on a page (put a full page image frame behind everything),
  - cover the old text with a white rectangle and
  - retype the text.

  Slightly better than tipexing on paper.
- If you're working with a development Scribus 1.5.x (or later)

  - you can load the PDF page as a vector,
  - remove the old text and
  - type the new text.

  But

  - The text will always be vectorized on import (no real editing is possible) and
  - it won't reflow.